# Get checked values of checkboxes from a table and use them in controller

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm using Symfony 3.4. I'd like to get checked values of checkboxes from a table and get these values in the controller for another process.

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Agent</th>
    <th>Sélectionner</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{% for agent in agents %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ agent.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ agent.fullname }}</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="idagent[{{agent.id}}]" value={{agent.id}}" />
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

In the controller

```
public function newinterneAction(Request $request)
{
...
$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $ids=$request->get('idagent');
    die(dump($ids));
}
}
```

But this return null. How can I make it with Symfony?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$request->getContent();`

Anyway, you should use https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html for creating forms

Comment: Ir returns " ". Do you have another idea?